# Watin; Get element by id not working

Tags: c#, watin

I am trying to place data into text area that is inside hidden input but watin does not find it.

When I search for inputs my program shows this:

[image]

```
 var ie = new WatiN.Core.IE("http://facebook.com", true);
 ie.ClearCookies();                                  ie.TextField(WatiN.Core.Find.ById("email")).TypeText(textBoxUsername.Text);                        ie.TextField(WatiN.Core.Find.ById("pass")).TypeText(textBoxPassword.Text);
 ie.Button(WatiN.Core.Find.ByValue("Login")).Click();
 ie.Link(WatiN.Core.Find.ByText("Status")).Click();                 
                    ie.TextField(WatiN.Core.Find.ById("u362110_11")).TypeText(textBoxPassword.Text);
```

Exception

```
Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'id' equals 'u493403_13' at http://www.facebook.com/home.php
```

Comment: The HTML above does not have the id ("u493404_13")   Are you sure the HTML and the code are proper?   It is very hard to read your HTML code though, so it is possible I missed it

Comment: text area id changes as page new loads.....

Comment: I see that you have a big javascript callback in the onfocus attribute. It is generally a bad practrice, you should put the callback and the binding to your element in a specific <script></script>, or better, in a separate .js file

Comment: its not me its facebook using this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working by replacing id by searching by name because id was dynamic and changed all the time

Comment: If there is any consistency for part of the IDs that are dynamically generated, you could also use regex to match with Find.ById

Comment: +1 This wasnt exactly what helped me. But I went back and took another look at my code after trying all sorts of other messy answers and it was because I used Find.ByName(("Field")) instead of Find.ByName(tableRow["Field"]). Yeah thats right, a keyword and square brakets cost me days of work. Still you live and learn! Cheers. :-)